# What tools support importing graphviz (.dot) files?

Tags: graphviz

I would like to import .dot files (Grpahviz) to any interactive editor (preferably draw.io). Unfortunately, I didn't find any tool that supports this file format.

Can you recommend any tool or converter? Thanks

Comment: yEd live has some support for graphwiz dot files. But graphwiz can expirt gml files so you should be able to use those.

Answer (score 5):

Your `.dot` (or `.gv`, see above) file is an input file for a Graphviz network diagramming system.  Don't know of any other system that will take the .dot file as input and create an equivalent output.

So, either [install Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/download/) – quite easy on a Windows system, pretty easy on many other OSs.

Or use [this online version](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/).

Either way, you can produce an SVG output and then (I think) import the SVG file into draw.io, or similar editor, like Inkscape.

[though not a Graphviz developer, I am associated with the Graphviz community]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python package, [graphviz2drawio](https://github.com/hbmartin/graphviz2drawio), that will convert a .dot file to an XML file that can be opened in draw.io. It is not in active development and hasn't had a new release since 2018, but I was able to install and use it with Python 3.10. The dependency on [PyGraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) was a little trouble, but that package is in active development and has good install instructions. The end result opened in draw.io and was editable as expected.

I also tested converting to .gml using the gv2gml command that ships with Graphviz. It imported into yEd Live, but the node and edge labels did not convert well and would need significant manual attention. yEd Live is also supposed to be able to import simple .dot files directly, but I couldn't get it to import anything I tried.